# Which technology should I use for a new app?

Tags: .net, angularjs

I have an idea (that seems to be great) and I would like to invest time on it to make it true. I'm an experienced programmer with background on .NET platform, especially in C# language, with good knowledge in Javascript, HTML, ASP.NET (MVC pattern), etc..  However, I see that the current trend is Angular along with some other recent technologies.

I'm afraid of investing time in an application using my current skills and it becomes obsolete so quickly. The reason of building it using my current knowledge is that I would be able to launch it more rapidly. On the other hand, I wonder if I should firstly learn about recent techologies (like Angular and Restful services such as Web API) before start something. My concern is that the learning-curve might be long and I would be losing time.

Any good advices?

Comment: It depends on the app you are going to write. I would go with ASP.NET Core :)

Comment: That would surely burn a lot of hours. At least it did for me when they changed all the tooling with every new beta release...

Comment: mmm does it matter how you convert your idea to app? Will it matter to your customers whether you do it in Angular or .NET or xyz? The trend will change again in couple years, technology are just tools, you use whatever you are comfortable with and get that thing built. My two cents - use sth that you are already comfortable with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in a similar position to yours in terms (in terms of knowledge). I was working primarily with MVC and just some javascript. I have since then learned how to use angular with REST on Web.Api. I don't regret it at all, it's a way better approach in my opinion.

Web Api will take you virtually no time to learn if you are familiar with MVC.
Angular is a bit more complex, and can burn some time (I guess a week or two should be enough for basics), but it is definitely worth in at least for the sake of knowledge. In my opinion it's a much more solid way of developing than some HTML manipulation with JQuery.

So it all depends on how much time you can "wait" and how much you want to invest in the knowledge for yourself.